# How to check Open GL API on device before starting GL rendering on a Qt for android app?

Tags: android, c++, qt, opengl-es

I am new to `Open GL`. My `QtApp on Android` which uses `OpenGL ES 3.0`. It works fine on GLES 3.0 compatible devices. But when I launch my app on a device which is `GLES 2.0` compatible, it launches but dies after a 5-6 seconds logging the following error.

```
E/libEGL  (24385): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
```

My app has only a small part of the screen that is doing gl rendering. The rest of the UI has buttons, menu & other things. My GL renderer currently has no check for the gl es API before starting the rendering and just tries to render. I want to allow app to launch & show the UI without the gl rendering when GL API is not 3.0. At the least app should not get killed.

*How should I check the Open GL ES capabilities of the device so that I don't start my renderer when device does not support Open GL ES 3.0 ? Or what are the best ways to deal with this problem ?*

Comment: Did you find this while searching for a solution: https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/09/09/cross-platform-opengl-es-3-apps-with-qt-5-6/

Comment: let me read this through. I am already doing the `setDepthBufferSize`